# Performance degrades when querying linked Oracle DB from MS SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

**UPDATE**

***I have noticed that when I do a simple view from this table, results come back fairly quickly, but as soon as a I make `WHERE` clause restriction it slows way down.***

I'm running a query that runs well, about 1.5 minutes. Yet when I include a single column from a linked Oracle DB the query takes 19 minutes. Is performance degradation like this normal?

I'm also not familiar with where I should start troubleshooting this type of issue, and am new Linked Servers.

Thank you,

**UPDATE**

Below is the code that creates the Oracle Linked Server DB view

```
 SELECT Patient
,Account
,MR#
,Diagnosis
,ICD9
,TransferEMTALAFormsCmpltd
,Disposition
,AdmittingDxTranscribed
,AxisIPrimaryDx
,AgeDOB
,sex
,age
,EDRecordSentToEDM
,TimeRNSignature
,timemdsignature
,RNSgntr
,TriageByNameEntered as 'Triage_End'
,TriageStartTime as 'Triage_Start'
,AddedToAdmissionsTrack
,StatusAdmitConfirmed
,SUBSTRING(statusadmitconfirmed,1,4)+'-'+SUBSTRING(statusadmitconfirmed,7,2)+'-'+SUBSTRING(statusadmitconfirmed,1,4)+' '+SUBSTRING(statusadmitconfirmed,9,2)+':'+SUBSTRING(statusadmitconfirmed,11,2)+':00.000' as 'Admit_Cnrfm_String'
,AdmittingMD
,AreaOfCare
,EDMD
,EDMDID
,Specialty
,AccessProceduresED
,MDSgntr
,Arrival
,ArrivalED
,ChiefComplaint
,TransferringFacility
,ReferMD
,PrivateName

FROM [BMH-EDIS-CL]..[WELLUSER].[Patient_Chart] a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN [BMH-EDIS-CL]..[WELLUSER].[Patient_Diagnoses] b
ON a.Master_Rec_Id=b.Master_Rec_Id 
    AND a.Slave_Rec_Id=b.Slave_Rec_Id



WHERE TriageStartTime > '201299999999'
```

Just getting a single result out of this view takes some time. When I try to add EDMD to the query I am working on, this is what causes the massive slow down, I have not yet been able to review Materialized Views as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Depends on the kind of link you have created.  Sounds like there is no materialization going on, so the system is going out and retrieving the data from the Oracle system, which introduces network latency along with the usual disk/IO latency.

Comment: I'll have to do some reading on that one, it's killing me to see queries degrade like this. Learning in progress.

Comment: It's not entirely unusual.  Fetching data from an linked server database is much more expensive.  1.5 minutes to 19 minutes is only one order of magnitude.  In my experience, one thing that often helps is creating a view that contains the query for the remote DB, and then use that query locally.  Even if it's effectively `SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(...`.  Honestly, though, even a 1.5 minute query would be unacceptable for me for most purposes.

Comment: @BaconBits the query is against a view, and yes 1.5 minutes is horrendous but I have inherited some queries that take 2 ~ 3 hours that need severe optimization so for now I'll accept 1.5 minutes...

Comment: couldnt the issue that you are querying a view on the oracle side that could just be eating that time?

I have a few of these running and my returns are instant unless i hva e huge query / view on the oracle side that runs as part of the overall query.

Comment: @lookslikeanevo it is possible, the view has more columns that I need for my query but the query isn't returning hundreds of columns by millions of rows.

Comment: doesnt matter if youre only returning 1 row from oracle. if it takes 18 minutes to run the query in oracle, its going to be slower via open query from sqlserver...

if you were to run a select * from the open query how long does it take?, how many fields are you joining on? are they all char?

Comment: @MCP_infiltrator Show your sample query and check http://sqlbits.com/Sessions/Event10/Distributed_Query_Deep_Dive